# Is there any Gradle plugin for scm like CVS?

Tags: java, build, cvs, gradle

I'm new to Gradle... Working on a simple build script for my java project.. We are using CVS for source management.. I couldn't find any CVS/SCM plugin in Gradle.. I believe I can create an ant task to access CVS and use it in my gradle script.. but is there any ready available CVS plugin?

Comment: I am not aware of any CVS plugin. You could probably probably just use the [Ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/cvs.html). You might be interested in following the feature request for [SCM support in Gradle](http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-181).

Comment: I can't find one either, but there is at [least one good standalone Java CVS client](http://versioncontrol.netbeans.org/javacvs/library/) so I imagine a Gradle plugin could be created relatively easily. There's just not that much interest in CVS anymore. Go figure :)

Comment: thanks for your reply.. I used ant task .. it is easy to use.. Works very well..

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, your Version Control interaction belongs at the Continuous Integration (CI) level.  You will want to use a product like Jenkins, Hudson, Bamboo, etc to check out the correct version of the project, and then just use Gradle to do the building of whatever version is present.

Comment: I agree with this in general but sometimes it makes sense for the build system to be able to query the SCM for some information.