# How can I checkout project from cvs using gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I have created gradle script to build my project but I want project to be downloaded from cvs repository. Is there any cvs plugin of gradle ?

Answer (score 0):

See this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15392070/1441857

As stated you'd usually not do that in the build script but in the CI. The answer is that there's probably not one for gradle. However should you actually need it for various reasons, it should be possible to create something like a shell script and execute it from gradle.

Comment: yes.. what I need to do is if I provide cvs repository details it should checkout project and then build using gradle.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to do dependency management? When searching the net I can't find anything immediately, so I still suspect that the answer is no, gradle can't immediately. As @Edvin-Syse says you could publish via some other tool, or build a local repository. Otherwise you can still call other commands from gradle and checkout projects via that. Perhaps you could call some other dependency system such as IVY to handle that?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Will use jenkins. In that will checkout using ant and build using gradle scripts.

Answer (score 0):

VCS is completely separate from your build system, simply use a CVS client to checkout your project.

If you want to distribute the project binaries you can publish to JCenter, Maven Central etc.